# How do I find the last character of an array name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So if I've got a few arrays, let's call them person1, person2, person3 and person4 and I've got a function that has an argument between 1 and 4, how can I select that specific array?

For example:

```
var person1 = ["Steve", "McStevey"];
var person2 = ["Mike", "McMikey"];
var person3 = ["Dave", "McDavey"];
var person4 = ["Joe", "McJoey"];
```

And if I run the function

```
getPerson(3);
```

and pass the argument to

```
function getPerson(x) {...}
```

the function uses to argument to determine that the array I'm looking for is person3.

Comment: An easy solution would be to use a switch case or multiple ifs. `if (x === 3) return person3; else if (x === 4) { ...`

Comment: Why aren't you using a 2-dimensional array? That way, the number you pass is just an index, and wou don't need to deal with variable numbers.

Comment: It depends on where the vars are defined, if they are global, you can use window[x], otherwise you'd have to use eval. A much better solution is to have arrays of arrays and just `persons[x]`

Comment: I am using a 2D array actually. I just used a 1D array in this example to make things simpler. Also, I'd prefer not to use switch/if because the number of person arrays can increase.

Comment: Don't do this. JS does not work with variable names as strings that you construct. In this case, use an array instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make an array of your person arrays:

`var persons = [person1, person2, person3, person4];`

`persons[x]` will then give you the right array. And as Redu mentioned, you can access person1 as `persons[0]`.

Comment: May be `persons[x-1]` is what you mean.

Comment: to access person3, you'd have to use `persons[2]`? could result in misleading code...

Comment: Maybe.... but these array names seem arbitrary already. Why not just make it person0, person1, etc. I don't think we have enough context to make a judgement.

Comment: Ended up going with this. Yep sorry I didn't give too much context, but this worked out for me!

Answer (score 1):

You should better define a map by ID with the persons.

```
var persons = {
  "1": ["Steve", "McStevey"],
  "2": ["Mike", "McMikey"],
  "3": ["Dave", "McDavey"],
  "123": ["Joe", "McJoey"]
}

function getPersonById(id) {
  return persons[id]
}
```

Comment: This is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to put your arrays in a lookup object.

```js
var object = {
  person1: ["Steve", "McStevey"],
  person2: ["Mike", "McMikey"],
  person3: ["Dave", "McDavey"],
  person4: ["Joe", "McJoey"],
};

function getPerson(x) {
  return object['person' + x];
}

console.log(getPerson(1));
```